# Git clean inside ignored folders

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder `foo` that is included in gitignore:

```
 - .gitignore  (this contains 'foo')
 - foo
    *
    *** bar
```

When I run `git clean -f` or `git clean -f -x`, this does not delete bar (bar is a normal file).

Is there a way to tell git to clean inside ignored folders?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`git clean -fdx` will delete all untracked files, including directories. The `-d` is necessary to cause the cleaner to descend into the untracked dir.