# "Permission denied" while building sbcl from source

Tags: build, common-lisp, sbcl

While compiling the sbcl from [source](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl) I am getting an error like:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/me/projects/sbcl/tools-for-build'
cc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I../src/runtime   determine-endianness.c  -ldl -o determine-endianness
make: Leaving directory `/home/me/projects/sbcl/tools-for-build'
make-config.sh: 677: make-config.sh: tools-for-build/determine-endianness: Permission denied
```

I tried it on the *master* branch and *sbcl-1.1.9* tag, `sudo`ed too. Following was tried too:

- `sh make.sh --prefix=/home/me/sbcl`
- `sh make.sh`
- `sh make.sh --prefix=/home/me/sbcl --xc-host='lisp -batch -noinit'`

but the same result.

What could be the matter and the fix?

Comment: it seems that the tools-for-build/determine-endianness is making that problem. Can you run that tool by iteself? If yes what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell what exactly was the problem but here are the things that I did.

Firstly I didn't have either have SBCL, CMUCL, OpenMCL,CLISP which the [Getting Started](http://sbcl.sourceforge.net/getting.html) instructs to.

So I did `sudo apt-get install clisp`. Other one's weren't available I guess.

Then I tried `sh make.sh "clisp"` but got another error, something to do with translation (can't recall). Then it struck to clean up the repo of garbage from the previous incomplete build.

`git clean -fd` didn't clean-up everything because of the `.gitignore` which also included `tools-for-build/determine-endianness`. So the question [Git clean inside ignored folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9314190/1309352) helped clean up the ignored files.

Then, I guess, I tried `sh make.sh "clisp"` which erred again. So, I `git clean ..`ed again and simply used something like `sh make.sh --prefix=/home/me/sbcl` and, *hurray*, it built successfully.